# Tabs to mobile accordion?

Tags: jquery, mobile, tabs, accordion, responsive

Can someone explain to me how to make full-page tabs appear as an accordion on mobile? Right now I have my tabs with media breaks so I get them to appear stacked (like an accordion) on mobile, but I can't figure out how to make it so that, when clicked, the information appears directly below that button rather than below the whole section of buttons.

What I have is styled using a code like this:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_full_page_tabs
I just want to know if it’s possible to take tabs like this and turn them into accordions on mobile.

Comment: can you give a test link to test? that would be more of help to help you :)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_full_page_tabs

What I have is styled using a code like this. I just want to know if it’s possible to take tabs like this and turn them into accordions on mobile. :) thanks!!